# Creating a vertical and horizontal sliding background image with jQuery

Tags: jquery, slideshow

Looking to create something similar to the sliding behavior found on http://2011.madebygrave.com

The background image slides vertically for each project and within each project you can slide horizontally.

How would I go about creating this behavior with query or are there any plugins that are capable of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the simple way:

its made by lot of div elements, its simple trick you should make a holder div and set width and height to 100% and overflow to hidden and you should position to relative for inner position absolute div like this:

```
<style>
.holder{
width:100%;
height:100%;
overflow:hidden;
}
</style>
<div class='holder'> </div>
```

then add your projects, for every item you should create a single div like this:

```
<style>
.item{
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
</style>
<div class="item">Project1</div>
```

then you need to set onclick of your buttons with change height of every previous div to 0 and set height of the current div to 100%

2011.madebygrave.com is same with upper way but change top of items not height, i write all codes you need for this way, here:

http://jsfiddle.net/4FCrw/

Comment: This helps a ton! How would I go about creating the horizontal scrolling behavior? On each project you can also move left and right.

Comment: yep, you should only change left attribute of element, in simple way for see, change all top with left and see what happen.

Comment: i updated code, check it again ;)